# How to combine hashmap with same key and their values?

Tags: android

I am populating some json data into my listview , i am storing it in Hashmap and then adding it to arraylist but i am facing some problems.

My code :

```
 try{
    final String result = response.body().string();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
    JSONArray foodintervalarray = new JSONArray(data);
    for (int j = 0; j < foodintervalarray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = foodintervalarray.getJSONObject(j);
        final String food_interval = 
        jsonObject1.getString(FOOD_INTERVAL);
        Log.i("food_interval ", "food_interval " + food_interval);
        String item_name = jsonObject1.getString(ITEM_NAME);
        Log.i("item_name ", "item_name " + item_name);
        final HashMap<String, String> menuMap = new HashMap<String, 
        String>();
        menuMap.put(FOOD_INTERVAL, food_interval);
        menuMap.put(ITEM_NAME, item_name);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foodintervallist.add(menuMap);
            ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new 
            ListViewAdapter(Diet_Order_Activity_New.this,
            foodintervallist);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);                  
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      });
}
```

Posting here is my LogCat :

```
food_interval: food_interval Breakfast
item_name: item_name Brown Bread
food_interval: food_interval Breakfast
item_name: item_name  Butter 
food_interval: food_interval Breakfast
item_name: item_name Papaya
food_interval: food_interval Breakfast
item_name: item_name Milk
food_interval: food_interval 10 A. M
item_name: item_name rice
food_interval: food_interval 11.30 Soup
item_name: item_name tomato soup
food_interval: food_interval Lunch
food_interval: food_interval Lunch
food_interval: food_interval 3.30 PM
```

/////////////// current listview results /////////////

```
Breakfast            Brown Bread
Breakfast            Butter
Breakfast            Papaya
Lunch                Paneer
Lunch                Roti
```

//////////// how i want my listview to look ///////////////

```
Breakfast   Brown Bread,Butter ,Paneer
Lunch       Paneer,Roti
```

Have food_interval of one type in one column and combine its items with comma 
for example instead of displaying Breakfast 5 times in one column and its items also getting displayed separately in another column , i should have one Breakfast and Brown bread , Butter , Papaya as its items combined
Lunch as one and its items combined

But i am getting Breakfast 5 times separately and its items separately in other column

How to achieve the above ?, please help

Thanks

Comment: What type is response.body() returning? Are using `Retrofit` ?if so, then no need for JSONArray parsing.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur i am using okhttp

Comment: Can you correctly reformat the question, showing what you intend the result to look like in a neat format.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur i have edited how i want my listview to look and how i cam currently viewing my listview

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use custom class to store the data.
create this class:

```
  public class MyStorage {
    public String name = "";
    public ArrayList<String> food = new ArrayList<String>();
    public MyStorage (String name, String food) {
    this.name  = name;
    this.food = food;
    }
        public appendIfSameName(String name, String new_food) {
    boolean appended = false;
    if (this.name.isEqual(name)) {
    ar.add(food);
    appended  = true;
    }
    return appended ;
    }
    }
```

Use this code instead of your

```
    private ArrayList<MyStorage> foodintervallist_new = new ArrayList<MyStorage>();

     try{
        final String result = response.body().string();
    ///your code here is not good
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
    ////

        JSONArray foodintervalarray = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int j = 0; j < foodintervalarray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = foodintervalarray.getJSONObject(j);
            final String food_interval = 
            jsonObject1.getString(FOOD_INTERVAL);
            Log.i("food_interval ", "food_interval " + food_interval);
            String item_name = jsonObject1.getString(ITEM_NAME);
            Log.i("item_name ", "item_name " + item_name);

    appendIfUniqueElement(item_name,food_interval);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new 
                ListViewAdapter(Diet_Order_Activity_New.this,
                foodintervallist_new);
                listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);                  
                listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
          });
    }
private void appendIfUniqueElement(String name, String food) {
boolean new_element = true;
for (int i = 0 ; i < foodintervallist_new.size() ; i++) {
if (appendIfSameName(name,food)) {
new_element = false;
break;
} else {
//add new
}

}
if (new_element )
foodintervallist_new.add(new MyStorage(name, food));
}
```

Comment: you mean to say customadapter ?

Comment: not only customadapter but new class instead of hashmap.

Comment: Thanx for time , the storage class should have food as string instead of arraylist right ?

Comment: You have to store food as array list. For breakfast you will have 5 elements. For launch 1 elements, etc.

Comment: @narahari_arjun , approve the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First off, get:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
...
});
```

out of the for loop.

You will also need to change:

```
menuMap.put(FOOD_INTERVAL, food_interval);<br>
menuMap.put(ITEM_NAME, item_name);
```

You need to add some logic here to check if the food_interval already exists as a hash in the map.
If it does not, use the put calls above.
If it does, "get" the map value, add the item name to the string with a comma and "put" the new string.  The new put will replace the old value.

I'll leave the code to you as an exercise.

Good night and good luck